# how to update database in prestashop 1.5

Tags: php, prestashop-1.5

Am currently developing a PrestaShop payment module and am having issues updating a custom column in the database

```
$sql = 'UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'Webpay_transactions` 
     SET `Customer_id` = '.(int)$customer->id.', 
         `ResponseCode`= '.pSQL($responsecode).',
         `ResponseDescription`='.pSQL($desc).',
         `ApprovedAmount`= '.(int)$transamount.',
         `ReturnedReference`= '.pSQL($retRef).',
         `CardNumber`='.(int)$cardNum.',
         `Order_reference`= '.(int)$this->module->currentOrder.'
         WHERE `TransactionRef` = '.(int)$txn_ref.'';
Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);
```

Comment: Which kind of "issues" do you have?

Comment: and the issue is ?

Comment: The query fails to update

Comment: I can't tell if there is any SQL error

Comment: And I need to deliver the job,  I have been on this issue all night

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out where the issue was coming from. the TransactionRef variable had special characters which were not proper;y escaped. I had to do some fact finding and I finally found a solution.

```
$txn_ref = "TXN|EDUCON|798004|6|131"

 Db::getInstance()->Execute('UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'Webpay_transactions` 
            set Customer_id =\''.(int)$customer->id.'\', 
                ResponseCode = \''.pSQL($responsecode).'\',
                ResponseDescription = \''.pSQL($desc).'\',
                ApprovedAmount = \''.(int)$transamount.'\',
                ReturnedReference = \''.pSQL($retRef).'\',
                CardNumber = \''.(int)$cardNum.'\',
                Order_reference = \''.(int)$this->module->currentOrder.'\'

            WHERE TransactionRef = \''.pSQL($txn_ref).'\'');
```